# Gradle's afterTest block is not being executed

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

This is my first time asking question here. So apologise if my description is not upto the mark.

I have a multi project repo in gradle. In test project's build.gradle I have configured test task as following.

```
test {
  afterTest { desc, res ->
     //print something
  }
}
```

I have verified that afterTest block is never executed. I cannot see any logs printed. However when I create dummy project with simple test and apply same configuration, I was able to see the logs.
What could be the problem and how can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

I have tried to create a dummy project and add similar afterTest block in test task. It worked. But it is not working for my original project.

Comment: Does it work if you add it to one of the submodules?

Comment: Yes. So I have two modules core and test. If I ad afterTest block in core->build.gradle and run tests from core it works fine. But it I add afterTest block in test->build.gradle it doesn't

Comment: Without a simple reproducible example, I'm going to be guessing 